# How do I get predicted probability in R, but using Stata's default settings?

Tags: r, stata

I have been using the `glm()` and `predict()` functions to get the projected probability for each respondent. I was wondering how can I instead use Stata's default setting for the average marginal effect (AME) rather than the mean value to get probability.

Specifically, I am trying to replicate a percentage value that another researcher obtained, but he is using Stata instead of **R**. 
He replied in an email:

> "*...The models were run with the default Stata settings for logit (other variables set at AME rather than at mean values). The estimated probabilities were from the same models using Stata's `margins` command*..."

Here is the code I have tried:

```
mylogit3<-glm(candidatebinary~educated+partybinary+marriagebianry+age+gender+childscaler+domscale+imscale+rrscale+econscale+ideologyscale,data=informedvoters,family="binomial")  

prob=predict(mylogit3,informedvoters,type="response")
```

I have also tried `margins()` from the margins package, which imports Stata's unique functions to **R**. I suppose my question really is how to use the `margins()` function in **R** to get the probability just as I would use `predict()` ordinarily.

Comment: Apologies, I am not familiar with Stata, but is [this vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/margins/vignettes/TechnicalDetails.pdf) close to what you are looking for?

Comment: Thanks your reply-- I already tried margins() from margins package, which imports STATA unique functions to R. I guess my question really is how to use margins function in R to get probability just as I would use predict() ordinarily.

Comment: At the bottom of page 16, [the vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/margins/vignettes/TechnicalDetails.pdf) mentioned above,  indicates that by default the `margins` function provides results on the probability scale.

Answer (score 0):

Stata's default for the `margins` command is to use the actual value of the covariates to predict and then take the average. For example:

```
/* Stata Code */

sysuse auto, clear
(1978 Automobile Data)

export delimited mpg foreign using "~/Desktop/cars.csv", replace
file /Users/dimitriy/Desktop/cars.csv saved

// Logit and predictions

quietly logit foreign mpg, nolog

margins

Predictive margins                              Number of obs     =         74
Model VCE    : OIM

Expression   : Pr(foreign), predict()

------------------------------------------------------------------------------
             |            Delta-method
             |     Margin   Std. Err.      z    P>|z|     [95% Conf. Interval]
-------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
       _cons |   .2972973   .0487662     6.10   0.000     .2017172    .3928773
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

```
/* R equivalent */

rsource, terminator(END_OF_R)
Assumed R program path: "/usr/local/bin/R"

Beginning of R output
>         library(foreign)
>         cars<-read.csv("~/Desktop/cars.csv")
>         logit<-glm(foreign~mpg,data=cars, family="binomial")
>         (margins<-mean(logit$fit))
[1] 0.2972973
```

Note that the *community-contributed* command `rsource` is employed here, which can run **R** from inside Stata using an **R** source file and/or inline **R** code.